# Iterate different links in JSONSerialization with DispatchQueue Swift

Tags: json, swift, serialization

I need to find a way to execute the code several times, editing the link according to the elements contained in the array "MisCursos", but my problem is in the DispatchQueue.main.async, because this will be inside the loop if I simply use a cycle For, replacing array values.

For example ->

```
for x in 0...MisCursos.count - 1 {
   let urlStringAsistencia = "https://losvilos.ucn.cl/tongoy/asist_marcar4.php?c=\(x)&s=\(idSemestreG)&op=list"
   ...
}
```

### CODE

```
var AsistenciasAll = [Asistencias]()  
var MisCursos = [MisCursosTon]()

MisCursos = [MisCursosTon(id: 639, nombre: "Análisis Financiero (ECIN-01084) {C2}", codigo: "asas", seccion: "C2", rol: "E"), MisCursosTon(id: 61, nombre: "Marketing (ECIN-01083) {C1}", codigo: "asassss", seccion: "C1", rol: "E"), MisCursosTon(id: 400, nombre: "Sistemas De Información I (ECIN-00986) {C1}", codigo: "asas", seccion: "C1", rol: "E")]

let urlStringAsistencia = "https://losvilos.ucn.cl/tongoy/asist_marcar4.php?c=\(x.id)&s=6&op=list"
let urlAsistencia = URL(string: urlStringAsistencia)
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:urlAsistencia!) { (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error!)
    } else {
        do {
            let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! NSDictionary
            for (key, value) in parsedData {
                ...

                let user = Asistencias(idCurso: 12, idAsistencia: key as! String, fecha: fecha, bloque: bloque, rut: rut, nombres: nombres, apellidos: apellidos, estado: estado, razon: razon, imgurl: imgURL)
            AsistenciasAll.append(user)
            }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error al Descargar Datos", message: "Al parecer ocurrió un error, vuelve a intentarlo", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Entendido", style: .cancel, handler: {
            action in self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)})
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }   
}.resume()
```

Comment: Displaying an alert for each one sounds like it would be pretty annoying for the user. Can you pop up a summary alert after they're all done?

Comment: It is precisely what I want to avoid, I want to perform multiple serializations, I don't anticipate many times going to iterate an array that contains a variable which is part of the link of where I want to extract the json, for example "https://losvilos.ucn.cl/tongoy/asist_marcar4.php?c=\(INSERT VAR HERE)&s=6&op=list" and when you are done iterating, throw the alert message. This is what I do not know how I can make

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API you need is `DispatchGroup`. That will allow you to group a bunch of asynchronous tasks together and notify you when all of them are complete. I'll outline the basics of what you need:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
for url in urls {
    // tell the group that a new task is being added
    group.enter()
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:urlAsistencia!) { (data, response, error) in
        // do parsing
        // tell the group that a task is done
        group.leave()
    }.resume()
}

group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
    // create summary alert
}
```

You'll probably also need to keep track of which tasks (if any) failed so you can notify the user.

**Note**: it is important that you call `group.leave()` in every completion handler, even if the task fails. Otherwise the group will be waiting around forever for a task that it thinks is still outstanding.

Comment: great! it works perfectly :) thanks!!! PD: Missing "}" after "}.resume" for the For loop @DaveWeston

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that typo. I've updated the code to correct it.